# workaround for mapview overlays not pinch-zooming correctly

Tags: android

If a user does a "pinch zoom" on the map, my overlays don't properly size until the end.  This has been noted in other posts, so i assume it is a known issue.

Problem is, my client finds it totally unacceptable, as I am tasked with making the android app look as good as the iphone version.

Is there any way to correct this, even if it is a horrible hack?  For instance, can I subclass the mapview and handle drawing or override some other method?

Comment: Could you add a little more information - how are you adding the overlay to the map - is it a custom application (mapview + map overlay), or are you using the standard map application and passing it a KML file? Reason I ask is it is not something I have come across, and I have just tested in one of my apps (mapView with an overlay) and the overlay changes as you are pinching (HTC desire) before the map has started to redraw itself at the new zoom level (that only happens once I let go of the pinch).

Comment: custom application with a mapview and map overlay.  I notice it happens in sample apps as well.  The actual google maps application behaves correctly, however.  (it may work on your htc desire because that is running a later version....t-mobile hasn't upgraded my model to 2.2 yet)

Answer (score 0):

The common solution is to not draw overlay during zoom animation.

**UPDATED:**
Sorry, I've confused zoom and move.
The problem with zoom is that you can't rely on zoom level. Instead you need to draw your overlay based on MapView.getProjection().

Comment: can you elaborate?  how do I detect when it is zooming and avoid drawing?  (note that, although one of my overlays I am drawing stuff directly, in another it just displays a set of markers using ItemizedOverlay )

Comment: Ok but I'm stil not sure what you mean.  I do use getProjection() where needed.  But I also have plain old markers done using ItemizedOverlay().  Both behave the same.